paypal_js_sdk_v5_unhandled_exception, Uncaught Error: Component closed
I've set up PayPal subscriptions on a React app I started working on 2 years ago. I started working on it again recently.
I'm getting 2 console errors: paypal_js_sdk_v5_unhandled_exception, and Uncaught Error: Component closed. I'm using @paypal/react-paypal-js and updated to the newest version.
Everything seems to be working fine with one exception: my app doesn't detect when the payment has been made. I have to send a request to my server again to check if the subscription has been registered. However, there's no direct callback that indicates that the subscription has been completed.
I also get warnings about third-party cookies

please include code in question
